# Yii2 Pjax update div with flash message issue

Tags: ajax, yii2, pjax

i've a problem with Pjax and Yii2.
I have a view with a select input.
When i select an option i load a form via Ajax into a modal window.
If i submit the form i'll make a second Ajax call to a Controller function. In the controller i set a flash message and return an array.
In my jquery code if i use Pjax to reload the div where i see the flash message the entire page is reloaded.

I use timeout false but i think the problem is because i made two ajax call and so pjax reload the entire page. How i can prevent this ?

Pjax container

```
<!-- START PJAX -->
{Pjax id='refresh-flash' timeout=false}
    {AlertBs4::widget(['options' => ['class' => 'show']])}
{/Pjax}
<!-- END PJAX -->
```

view

```
<div class="modal" id="modal-form" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" style="max-width:900px;" >
        <div class="modal-content" >
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
               <!-- Here goes the form -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="apiCall" data-pjax="0">Ok</button><!-- this button makes the second ajax call -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          
          //Get Starter html
          let html_start =  $('.modal-body').html();
                   
          $('#eventi-event_trasp').on('change',function(){
                let trasp = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '$url',
                    type: 'get',
                    data: {
                        trasp_cod : trasp
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data){
                            $('.modal-body').empty();
                            $('.modal-body').append(data);
                            $('#modal-form').modal('show');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                         console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                
          });   
                    
          //Click ok from form loaded via ajax
          $('#apiCall').on('click',function(event){
                
                 $.ajax({
                    url: $('#form_corrieri').attr('action'),
                    type: 'post',
                    data: $('#form_corrieri').serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        // THIS CAUSE RELOAD ENTIRE PAGE
                        //$.pjax.reload({container: '#refresh-flash', async: false, timeout: 0 ,push: false, replace: false});
                        $('#eventi-eventi_info').val(data);
                        $('#modal-form').modal('hide');
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                         console.log('error');
                    }
                });
                //$.pjax.click(event, {container: '#refresh-flash'})
                
                
          });
```